# What's the use of Firebase Personal Content Indexing?

Tags: android, android-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

I go through the firebase app indexing android document but it's not quite clear for me that what's the use of Firebase Personal content indexing.

What's the use-case to index personal contents?

I've to log user action if I want to show application content as a autocomplete in Google App search bar. I understand that I have to index the content before I log the action on that content.

Comment: It's actually explained in the [Firebase documentation page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/personal-content).